# How to store select statement result to table variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @T_variable table(name varchar(200))
SET @T_variable =(SELECT au_lname FROM Testing)
```

> Error Message. Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@T_variable".

Note :- select statement result will give multiple rows.

I try to capture the select result in table variable.But i failed.
Is there any way to capture the select result to Table variable Dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try below query instead since you have declared a table variable instead of a datatype variable.

```
Declare @T_variable table(name varchar(200))
insert into @T_variable 
SELECT au_lname FROM Testing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @T_variable :=(SELECT au_lname FROM Testing)
```

Adding a colon may help here.

Comment: Is your answer better than the selected answer?

Comment: someone may find this useful.@jhhoff02